# unable to record a WebUI using katalon studio

Tags: google-chrome, katalon-studio

I tried to record a web UI and run the test using Katalon studio. To record web, I entered the URL in web recorder and selected chrome as the browser. The browser is opened but not the site. Instead, I received error messages. The same case happened when I chose Firefox as the browser to record. The error messages I got are present in below.

> session not created
>   from disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
>     (Session info: chrome+71.0.3578.98)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210)
>   (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 2.39 seconds
>   Build info: version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a', time: '2017-11-06T21:07:36.161Z'
>   System info: host: 'DESKTOP-54HVVNN', ip: '10.13.209.50', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
>   Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

[image: Screenshot of above quoted error message]

Answer (score 0):

Could you tried to update the chromedriver?
Here is the instruction:
WINDOWS
Selenium

Download the desired Selenium version here. (Select only Selenium 3.0+ and higher version than 3.7.1)
Delete existing selenium-server-standalone-3.x.jar
Copy preferred driver into this folder
\configuration\resources\lib
Chromedriver

Download preferred Chromedriver here.
Copy downloaded Chromedriver and paste into Katalon Studio folder
You can use 32-bit Windows Chromedriver for both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows.

\configuration\resources\drivers\chromedriver_win32
\configuration\resources\drivers\chromedriver_win64
Firefox (Gecko Driver)

Download preferred Gecko Driver here.

Copy downloaded Gecko driver and paste into Katalon Studio folder

\configuration\resources\drivers\firefox_win32
\configuration\resources\drivers\firefox_win64

more information could be found at: https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/update-or-replace-web-browser-drivers-and-selenium.html#how-to-replace

Comment: I updated the latest version of Chromedriver as well but the results were same

Comment: I received the same error message that I received earlier. The one which I have posted as an attachment above.